# Why backslashes are being added to all the $_GET, $_POST automatically?

Tags: php, quotes, cpanel

I have a vps with cPanel/Whm/CentOS 5.5 and the problem is that all parameters sent to my server are being *addslashed*, I've checked out the PHP configuration and i found out that all the magic quotes are turned off and i don't know what causes this.

My code is so clean and i know every bit of it and i don't have any `addslashes()` or some sort of these functions. i only want to receive the parameters as they are.

```
URL: test.php?text=blah" ' " 'blah

<?php
echo $_GET["text"]; // Output blah\" \' \" \'blah
?>
```

How to turn off this thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) variable in your php.ini (this is the first place to turn it off). You should really check of you are looking at the right file.

You can also turn it off in .htaccess or at runtime I believe. But if your host doesn't won't let you do either of these things you can use the following function that will word regardless of the current setting.

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

    $_POST      = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
    $_GET       = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
    $_COOKIE    = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST   = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}

function stripslashes_deep($value) {

    return (is_array($value) ? array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) : stripslashes($value));
}
```

Comment: thanks, but as i described i've already magic quotes turned off.

Comment: You should really check of you are looking at the right file. Use phpinfo() to output all your current settings, including the location of the php.ini that was used. Maybe the setting was off in php.ini but set on at runtime. This should also be visible in a phpinfo() output. You can also var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) to get the current value of the magic_quotes setting.

Comment: Thanks! before, i've checked out the php configuration section in whm and i clicked to edit the magic quotes gpc then i found out that it's already off , but it's not, i had to save it again

Answer (score 2):

You have to [disable magic_quotes_gpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Answer (score 1):

It's a (deprecated) security feature called "[magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)," and it's possible to turn it off.