# Trouble decoding JSON string with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm trying to send an array of objects from JS to PHP using JSON.  I have an array of players as follows:

```
var player;
var players = new Array();
//loop for number of players
player = new Object();
player.id = theID;
players[i] = player;
```

Then my AJAX call looks like this:

```
JSONplayers = JSON.stringify(players);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "php/ajax_send_players.php",
data: {
    "players" : JSONplayers
}
```

On the PHP side the decode function looks like this

```
$players = $_REQUEST['players'];
echo var_dump($players);
$players = json_decode($players);
echo 'players: ' .$players. '--'. $players[0] . '--'. $players[0]->id;
```

Debugging in chrome, the JSON players var looks like this before it is sent:
JSONplayers: "[{"id":"Percipient"},{"id":"4"}]"

And when I vardump in PHP it looks OK, giving this:
string(40) "[{\"id\":\"Percipient\"},{\"id\":\"4\"}]"

But I can't access the PHP array, and the echo statement about starting with players: outputs this:
players: ----

Nothing across the board...maybe it has something to do with the \'s in the array, I am new to this and might be missing something very simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**note** I've also tried json_decode($players, true) to get it as an assoc array but get similar results.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why backslashes are being added to all the $_GET, $_POST automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359854/why-backslashes-are-being-added-to-all-the-get-post-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to emulate some data:

```
var message = [
    {id: "90"},
    {"id": 123},
    {"id": 456},
    {"id": 87.5},
    {"id": 123.1}
];
```

I used your javascript and added a success handler to use the output of the PHP file:

```
JSONplayers = JSON.stringify(message);
alert(JSONplayers);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxTest.php",
    data: {
        "players": JSONplayers
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#myId').html(data);
    }
});
```

Then I tweeked your PHP a little bit:

```
<?php
    $players = $_REQUEST['players'];
    $json = json_decode(stripslashes($players),true);
    foreach($json as $row) {
        echo $row['id'] . '<br />';
    }
?>
```

This kicks out a new line for each entry and references it by its key (id).